# Can't create unit test with FireStore for flutterfire, throws during init, even with simplest possible test

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  group('core tests - coffee', () {
    test('fetch coffees', () async {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

      print('initialized');
      expect(firestore, isNotNull);
    });
  });
}
```

This is in a test.  Oddly, it works in the live app, but not in a simple test case.
Errors during `Firebase.initializeApp()` with:

```
Null check operator used on a null value
MethodChannel.binaryMessenger
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:121
```

I don't want a testWidgets.  I don't want a mocked FireStore.  I want to hit the real database.

I'm on a mac, running a simulator, using VSC, although the simulator shouldn't even be involved.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase plugins wraps around native platform (firebase) SDKs and i think they are not available on when running tests.
I would suggest to use either the emulator suite or fake_cloud_firestore package, or do manual testing by humans (connected with a different firebase instance)

Comment: Again, I'm looking for a unit test, with live Firestore.  I don't see why this is so hard.  Maybe there's some magical formula for this?